# Firemonkey TImageControl zoom

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, firemonkey-fm2

I want to modify the way the TImageViewer in Firemonkey handles the zoom.  When I roll the mouse wheel the image should zoom, but the image should not Center.  Instead the pixel that was at the position of the mouse before the zoom must still be at the position of the mouse after zoom.  Hence it should work the same as the Windows Photo Viewer.

I am using XE3 and programming in Delphi.